# Changing a function to use vectors instead of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm getting a little stuck changing functions to use vectors. I've got the below function that creates a new dynamic array. Now I need to do the same but use vectors.

```
int *makeData(int size)
{
    int *ptr = nullptr;
    ptr = new int[size];
    return ptr;
}
```

This is all i got so far and can't seem to figure out what to do next.  Do i need a pointer to return?

```
int *makeData(int size)
{
    vector<int> data(100);
}
```

This function seems to be okay but is there a way to optimize it (make it simpler, and cleaner).

```
void getMovieData2(vector<int> data, int num)
{
int temp;
cout << "Enter the number of movies each student saw.\n";

for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
{
    cout << "Student " << (count + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> temp;
    data.push_back (temp);

    while (arr[count] <= 0)
    {
        cout << "The number of movies be greater than zero.\n";
        cout << "How many movies were seen by Student " 
             << (count + 1) << "? ";
        cin >> temp;
        data.push_back (temp);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @tadman Why on earth would you deal in pointers to vectors?

Comment: You don't show a call to makeData (either one)   Neither makeData function makes sense:   The first one could be replaced with 'ptr = new int[size];' The second one is going to crash and burn unless you fix because you can't return a vector as an int*.   I think you need to take a deep breath, delete this question; start all over and if you come up with a question that can actually be answered submit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `makeData` for vectors would be

```
vector<int> makeData(int size) {
    return vector<int>(size);
}
```

As you see it is effectively the same as

```
vector<int> data(size);
```

However it can be useful if you use auto consistently

```
auto data = makeData(size);
```

As of your `getMovieData` function: no, that function is not working as expected. You are passing a vector as value and are "returning" data in it - except that you are putting your data into a local copy that will be destroyed when the function returns.

The solution is to use a reference, as in

```
void getMovieData(vector<int> &outData, int count);
```

However I suggest you simply return a new vector

```
vector<int> getMovieData(int count);
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention copy elision (RVO) as your motivation for the last bit.

Answer (score 6):

Using a vector has made the `makeData` function redundant. It doesn't do anything that simply declaring a variable of type vector doesn't already do better.

Cleaning up the other function is possible, but has nothing to do with the question about vectors.

Also, none of this has anything to do with overloading.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the overloading term. Also I think the cleanup part is relevant because it shows the confusion between pointers, arrays and vectors.

Comment: The assignment is to write two functions that in essence do the same (overloading may not be the best word but in essence its the same concept). One function would use a dynamic array and the other a vector.